# image in block of StreamField is not recognized

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

This error is shown:

'image' tag should be of the form {% image self.photo max-320x200 [ custom-attr="value" ... ] %} or {% image self.photo max-320x200 as img %}

with line 19            {% image block.value as mein_bild %}

My template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static wagtailcore_tags wagtailimages_tags %}

{% block content %}

  <div class="notiert">
    <header>
      <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
    </header>
   <div class="body">
     {{ page.kurzfassung|richtext }}
     <p>{{ page.first_published_at }}</p>
     {% for block in self.notiert_feld %}
        {% if block.block_type == 'image' %}
           <p>in if image {{ block.value }}</p> 
           {% image block.value as mein_bild %}
           <img {{ mein_bild }} width=530 > 
        {% else %}
          {{ block.value }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>    
  </div>
```

{% endblock %}

Line 18 I have used for debugging. If I delete line 19 and 20 the name of the image is shown.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I tried this variant and got an error. But now it works.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static wagtailcore_tags wagtailimages_tags %}



{% block content %}


  <div class="notiert">
    <header>
      <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
    </header>
      <div class="body">
         {{ page.kurzfassung|richtext }}
         <p>{{ page.first_published_at }}</p>
         {% for block in self.notiert_feld %}
            {% if block.block_type == 'image' %}
                {% image block.value width-530 %}
            {% else %}
                {{ block.value }}
            {% endif %}
         {% endfor %}
    </div>    
  </div>




{% endblock %}
```

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

As documented at https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/topics/images.html, you need to include a resize rule to indicate the size that the image should be rendered at. If you don't want the image to be resized, use `original` (although keep in mind that it may break your page layout and/or waste bandwidth if an editor uploads an oversized image):

```
{% image block.value original as mein_bild %}
```